# How can I make a script to count up by fives?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I was trying to make a very simple bash script to list all of the multiples of five between 375 and 3500 (375, 380, 385...).  One thing that I tried and didn't work is:

```
for i in {375..3500}
do
        echo $i
        (($i += 5))
done
```

I gave up after a while and wrote this in BASIC in about 15 seconds:

```
10 count = 375
20 print count
30 count = count+5
40 if count < 3500 then goto 20
```

How can I make my BASIC program in a bash script?

Comment: this is better on stack overflow - Unix & Linux is about the OS, not coding. Coding is for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Alternatively a traditional C-style for loop can be used:

```
for ((i=375; i<=3500; i+=5)); do
    echo $i
done
```

This is perhaps less clear than using seq, but it doesn't spawn any subprocesses. Though since I'm familiar with C, I wouldn't have any difficulty understanding this, but YMMV.

Comment: Downside of this method is that it's less portable. The seq method works in POSIX sh.

Comment: Oh, do C-style for loops not exist in POSIX sh? You learn something new every day...

Comment: @WouterVerhelst Well, except for if you're limited to POSIX sh, you're not likely going to have seq, which is part of GNU coreutils. busybox has a more limited implementation, but outside of that, many embedded systems likely won't have it at all.

Comment: @Muzer -- at least `dash` does not support it. @ChrisDown -- There's no reason why "POSIX sh" *has* to imply "no seq". But yeah, granted, I had overlooked the fact that seq isn't specified by POSIX.

Answer (score 27):

Since you use brace expansion anyway, so make use of its feature fully:

```
echo {375..3500..5}
```

You can also use this technique to print each number in separate line with optional text by using `printf` instead of `echo`, for example:

```
$ printf "Number %s is generated.\n" {375..3500..5}
Number 375 is generated.
Number 380 is generated.
Number 385 is generated.
...
```

---

**Edit**

As pointed out by @kojiro in the comment Mac OS uses bash 3 as the default shell, which doesn't support increment in sequence expression of brace expansion. You need to upgrade to bash version 4 or use other shell which supports that (e.g. recent zsh).

Comment: This doesn't work for me on Mac OS 10.10.3.  It outputs '{375..3500..5}'.

Comment: @aswine that's why you should _always_ mention your OS when asking. Especially since OSX has a number of differences both from other UNICEs and from Linux.

Comment: This isn't an OS difference per se. It's a version difference. OS X only has BASH 3 OOTB. You can install a BASH from this century using almost any OS X package manager. I use Home Brew, for one.

Comment: I updated bash, and still:
`'$ echo {375..3500..5}
{375..3500..5}


$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.33(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.`

Comment: @aswine: You may not be running the version you installed; give a try to `bash -c 'echo {375..3500..5}'`. Not that this will not print newlines after each number, so this may still not be what you are looking for.

Comment: @dhag, that works, but I'm pretty sure if `bash --version` prints `version 4.3.33`, I'm running version 4.3.33.

Comment: The fact that the expansions fails run directly but succeeds in `bash -c` pretty much guarantees that two different shells are involved. Does `$SHELL --version` say it's bash 3?

Comment: @aswine if you just upgraded bash then you need to start new terminal or run `exec bash` in the current one. @dhag if one wants new lines instead of spaces then `printf '%s\n' {375..3500..5}` is possible workaround.

Comment: @dhag, oh, that's interesting.  `$SHELL --version` says 3, and `bash --version` says 4, even though I set iTerm to run `/usr/local/Cellar/bash/4.3.33/bin/bash --login`, rather than "Login shell".  Even after I open a shell and manually run `/usr/local/Cellar/bash/4.3.33/bin/bash --login`, `$SHELL --version` still says 3.  I guess I have some things to learn about changing shells.

Comment: @terdon - that's ridiculous. This website is *about* the OS. ***Unix/linux***. That's plenty specific. Answers on a website named ***Unix/linux*** which do not work for ***Unix/linux*** systems might not be covering all bases, wouldn't you say? If the answer doesn't, then it should probably mention why - it's completely ass-backwards to expect the asker on such a site to narrow the applicability of an answer. Rather the *answer* should specify how and why it might or might not suit the needs of an *asker* of a general ***Unix/linux*** system. Why would you have it otherwise?

Comment: @mikeserv first off, tone it down. Stop with the characterizations . There's no need to be rude. Second, my point is that the different tools, such as grep, that are available by default differ depending on the OS. Therefore, one should always mention the target OS.

Comment: @terdon - no - I'm tired of seeing that. It's discouraging to askers for any *os* which is not *yours*. I know exactly why you say that. And your point is ***not valid*** - again if there is some narrowed scope in an answer, then it is the responsibility of the one writing that answer to state it. It's flat ridiculous to expect the *asker* to do that for you. The best answers on a q/a site named ***Unix/linux*** will apply to ***all Unix/linux***  systems.

Comment: @mikeserv bad mood today? You cannot expect from the answer to cover all possible systems and all shells in all versions. That is impossible. On the other hand I understand OP didn't write the system - he didn't expect it does matter. But even reading something what not directly points your case widens your perspective and is beneficial. In this particular case, it appeared that OP uses bash 3, but from this answer he discovered that in bash 4 he can do this simpler - he upgraded, and maybe will stay with bash 4. Isn't this beneficial? If you think the answer is wrong you can always downvote.

Comment: @jimmij - yeah ... *what's it to you?* - No just kidding. I'm fine. He didn't discover that from this answer - he discovered it in the comments. If the answer had said... *for **Unix/linux** systems w/ `bash` v. 4 shells or later...* - which would have been a plenty simple thing to say, then he might very well have discovered it from the answer. So why don't you? That's all I'm saying. To expect the asker to do that for you is backwards. Look at Stephane's answers on this site - I think you'll find that's exactly the kind of thing he would do, and his answers are pretty model-worthy, I think.

Comment: @mikeserv The answer is very simply - I didn't write that because I had no idea in which version of `bash` this feature was introduced. I've learnt it myself from kojiro comment. And please do not compare me with SC, I really do not know all the details and history of all shells since late 1970. Once again - If you expect that, just please downvote.

Comment: I'm not going to downvote this answer - though I would upvote it if you made only that small change, and it may be I'm not alone in that. Definitely it would be more helpful to future readers. I'm not comparing you to sc, but you ***do know*** this answer is only applicable to users of `bash` v4 and later. Why would you withhold that information? In any case, the *reason* Mac only ships `bash` v3 is a pretty general one: GPL v2. `bash` v4 is GPL v3 licensed - and that is a bar *many* UNIX systems simply can't or won't meet.

Comment: @mikeserv I added that information, hope you are content.

Comment: Don't do it for me - though I do believe it is a better answer for it. But if you don't - then what does my opinion matter? If you do believe so, though, then you'll know the upvote you just received was justified.

Comment: @aswine, @dhag  `$SHELL --version` is unreliable. Use `echo $BASH_VERSION` or  `$BASH --version` to see the version. Or simply press `Control-x`, `Control-v`

Answer (score 17):

Using SEQ(1)

```
for i in $(seq 375 5 3500)
do
    echo $i
done
```

Or, simply:

```
seq 375 5 3500
```

Comment: Even simpler would be to drop the loop and just use `seq 375 5 3500`.

Answer (score 11):

Your for-loop snippet didn't work as you require for two reasons:

- `(($i += 5))` - here the `$i` is expanded to the value of `i`.  Thus the expansion will be something like `((375 += 5))`, which doesn't make sense (attempting to assign a literal number to another literal number).  This would normally be achieved with `((i += 5))` (no `$` to expand the variable)
- The `{375..3500}` will be expanded before the first iteration of the loop.  It will be the list of numbers `375 376 ... 3499 3500`.  For each iteration of the loop, `i` will get assigned to each of these numbers, one-by-one.  Thus at the start of each iteration, `i` will be reassigned to the next value in that list, counting up in steps of 1.  The `((i += 5))` effectively does nothing - it does add 5 to i, but then i is just reassigned again at the start of the next iteration.

I think I like the `for (( ; ; ))` answer best, but here are some alternatives to get you thinking:

---

Since we're dealing with multiples of 5, and the `{a..b..i}` expansion is not supported in bash version 3.2.57(1) (in OS X), then we can do this slightly arcane thing instead:

```
for i in 375 {38..349}{0,5} 3500; do
    echo $i
done
```

This demonstrates how bash can be used to create a cartesian product.

---

I think in general a for loop is the most convenient way to do this, but if you're interested, you can use a while-loop (a bit closer to your BASIC) program:

```
count=375
while (( count <= 3500 )); do
    echo $count
    (( count += 5 ))
done
```

Comment: @jimmij ... what's a Cartesian product? you can downvote the comment if you want, and I won't even care if you tell me. I'm curious.

Comment: @mikeserv you cannot downvote the comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product

Comment: @jimmij - it's still ok with me if you do.

Comment: @jimmij The devil are you talking about? A Cartesian product is a set of tuples of every possible combination of elements from two sets (which may or may not be the same set). More colloquially, it's just "all the possible combinations" from two groups of things. I only see one set. How is there a Cartesian product here?

Comment: @jpmc26 You are right, it is "all possible combinations", so lets plot two axis - on first write all numbers from `38` till `349`. On second only two numbers: `0` and `5`. Now lets create ordered pairs of those all combinations - you can write them as a sets: `{38,0}`, `{38,5}`...`{349,5}`, or just remove redundant symbols `{`, `,` and `}` and get... new numbers `380`...`3495`.

Comment: @jpmc26 The two sets we are taking the cartesian product of here are `{38..349}` and `{0,5}`.  The element-wise products are simply concatenations in this case.

Comment: @jimmij Pardon me. I think I was blind at the moment I wrote that.

Answer (score 5):

While there is, of course, an app for that (`seq 375 5 3500`), there are various ways of doing this from the commandline. While the fastest and simplest will be just using `seq`, here are some other options:

```
for i in {375..3500}; do [[ (($i % 5)) -eq 0 ]] && echo $i; done

i=370; while [ $i -le 3500 ]; do printf "%s\n" $((i+=5)); done

perl -le '$i=shift;while($i<=$ARGV[0]){print $i; $i+=5; }' 375 3500
perl -le 'map{print $_ + 5} 370..3495'

awk 'BEGIN{ for(i=375;i<=3500;i+=5){print i}}'
```

Comment: Nit pick: `$(($i % 5))` can be written `$((i % 5))`.

Answer (score 4):

POSIXly:

```sh
i=370
while [ 3500 -gt "$i" ]
do    echo "$((i+=5))"
done
```

...or...

```
echo 'for(x=370;x<=3500;x+=5)x' |bc
```

I dunno why you'd do it any other way. Excepting, of course...

```
seq 375 5 3500
```

...or with `dc`:

```
echo '370[5+pd3500>p]splpx'|dc
```

Comment: I'm curious as to how the `dc` code works. It's certainly more intriguing than using `seq`.

Comment: @dhag - it writes a little loop. it `s`aves the `[` string `]` to the top of the `p` array, then `l`oads it back onto the top of stack and e`x`ecutes it as a macro. Within the macro we push `5` on the stack then pop it and the second from top and `+` them, replacing both stack values with their sum, which is `p`rinted and `d`uplicated before `3500` is pushed on the stack, when we pop it and the dupe we just made for comparison `>`. If `3500` is greater, we load and execute as a macro the string stored in the `p` array *(our current macro)*, or if not break.

Answer (score 3):

If you're stuck on Bash 3:

```
echo {375..3500} | tr ' ' '\n' | sed -n 'p;n;n;n;n'
```

and if you prefer `awk`:

```
echo {375..3500} | tr ' ' '\n' | awk '!((NR-1)%5)'
```

I didn't know about brace expansion -- that is seriously cool.